# How to assign a group to a user based on their email domain in Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, customer-group

I want during the registration process to assign a different group to users that have a specific domain e-mail:

So a user with:
abc@domain.com
123@domain.com
…@domain.com
will be assigned to a specific group all others will be assigned to the default group.

I searched a lot, but I found only solutions for Magento 1.

Thank you

I'm trying to make it work, but it's not working.
I create **events.xml** in **app\code\Sieu\Extension\etc** with this code:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="customer_register_success">
        <observer name="vendor_extension_customer_register_success" instance="Sieu\Extension\Observer\Customer\RegisterSuccessObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```

next I created file **RegisterSuccessObserver.php** here.
**app\code\Sieu\Extension\Observer\Customer** with this code:

```
<?php
namespace Sieu\Extension\Observer\Customer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class RegisterSuccessObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function __construct() { }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
        $DiscountGroup=4;
        $GuestGroupId=1;
        list($user, $domain) = explode('@',$customer->getEmail());

        if ($domain == 'mydomain.com'):
            /* set Customer group as DiscountedGroup*/
            $customer->setData('group_id',$DiscountGroup);   
        else:
            $customer->setData('group_id',$GuestGroupId);   
        endif;
    }
    $customer->save();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create `registration.php` file here in your custom module

> app/code/Sieu/Extension/registration.php

Content for this file is..

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Sieu_Extension',
    __DIR__
);
```

Now you need to create `module.xml` file here in `etc` directory here

> app/code/Sieu/Extension/etc/module.xml

Content for this file is..

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Sieu_Extension" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
</config>
```

Now create `events.xml` file here in `etc` directory

> app/code/Sieu/Extension/etc/events.xml

Content for this file is..

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="customer_register_success">
        <observer name="sieu_customer_account_create_post" instance="Sieu\Extension\Observer\Customer\RegisterSuccessObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Now create one Observer file here

> app/code/Sieu/Extension/Observer/Customer/RegisterSuccessObserver.php

Content for this file is..

```
<?php
namespace Sieu\Extension\Observer\Customer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class RegisterSuccessObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $customer;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customer
    ) {
        $this->customer = $customer;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer){
        $customerEmail = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer()->getEmail();
        $DiscountGroup=4;
        $GuestGroupId=1;
        $customerId = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer()->getId();
        $customer = $this->customer->load($customerId);
        list($user, $domain) = explode('@',$customerEmail);

        if ($domain == 'soluzioni-internet.eu'):
            /* set Customer group as DiscountedGroup*/
            $customer->setGroupId($DiscountGroup);   
        else:
            $customer->setGroupId($GuestGroupId);   
        endif;
        $customer->save();

        return $observer;
    }  
}
```

Hope this will work for you!

Comment: Great Kishan, you solved my question. Thank you for your support.

Comment: You're welcome :)